# Insert Line Split after the first group in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to display line separator above the group headers but not on the first groupheader for eg.

```
              Name   Course    DateJoined     SummerCamp
Class A
1
2
3
_____________________________________________________________
Class B
1
2
3
____________________________________________________________
Class C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a line in group footer of that group.

Edit................................

On supress part of the group footer write below code.

```
If onlastrecord 
Then true 
Else false
```

Comment: Now I see the horizontal line at the bottom of the report. How do i get rid of it?

Comment: I've my info displayed within a box, the box is placed in the detail section. I see an extra line below the bottom of the box.